# Change NSURLConnection from sendSynchronousRequest to sendAsynchronousRequest?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, sendasynchronousrequest

My Code for NSURLConnection with sendSynchronousRequest works fine but how can i change it to an async request? i tried a lot but nothing would work.

if the Request is empty i´ll get an empty Array with [[]] .
How can i catch it for an Alert Message?

Please help ...

```
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.xyz.at/sample.php";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *postWerte = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@", self.textfeld.text];

    [body appendData:[postWerte dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    const char *convert = [returnString UTF8String];
    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:convert];
    NSMutableArray *meinErgebnis = [responseString JSONValue];

    NSString *cycle = @"";

    NSString *kopfdaten = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sendungsart: %@\r\nGewicht: %@ kg\r\n\r\n", [[meinErgebnis objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"ParcelTypeDescription"], [[meinErgebnis objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Weight"]];

    cycle = [cycle stringByAppendingString:kopfdaten];

    for(int i = 1; i < meinErgebnis.count; i++)
        {

        NSString *myValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@     PLZ: %@\r\nStatus: %@\r\n\r\n",
                [[meinErgebnis objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"EventTimestamp"],
                [[meinErgebnis objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"EventPostalCode"],
                [[meinErgebnis objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ParcelEventReasonDescription"]];

        cycle = [cycle stringByAppendingString:myValue];

        }
        self.ergebnis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cycle];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [self.textfeld resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: You should show the code where you tried to make the async request, so someone can help you fix that.

Comment: In your `for` loop, did you mean to skip the first entry with an index of zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

- create an `NSOperationQueue`, and
- call `sendAsynchronousRequest`, placing all of your `NSData` processing code inside the completion block.

Thus, instead of:

```
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

// now process resulting `data`
```

Use:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    // now process resulting `data`
}];
```

Alternatively, you could implement the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods. For more information on that, see the [Using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) section of the *URL Loading System Programming Guide.*

---

You say "if the request is empty": I assume you mean "if the data returned is empty". And you say it is `[[]]`. If that's really what you're getting, it sounds like an array with one item (which itself, is an empty array). Or is it `[]` (which is an empty array)? Or is it `nil`?

I'm going to assume that the data returned was `[]`, an empty array.

I'd also suggest you consider using `NSJSONSerialization`, the built in JSON parser, but obviously you can use `JSONValue` if you really want.

Finally, your implementation is skipping the first entry (`NSArray` uses a zero-based index). I'm assuming that was unintentional.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%s: sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
        return;
    }

    NSError *parseError;
    NSArray *meinErgebnis = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

    if (parseError) {
        NSLog(@"%s: JSONObjectWithData error: %@", __FUNCTION__, parseError);
        return;
    }

    if ([meinErgebnis count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"%s: meinErgebnis empty", __FUNCTION__);
        return;
    }

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in meinErgebnis)
    {
        // now process each dictionary entry in meinErgebnis
    }

    // etc.
}];
```